# Android: Google Calendar API, public events for all users

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I  decided to use [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) for my running app. I need to have some default public events in my calendar, this way anybody who is logged with different Google accounts could see them.

The questions is, what is the easiest way to store events, that everybody, who is logged from different accounts could see them?Maybe  I need to create main events calendar and share to other local calendars?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the use of [Extended Properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties) which makes it easy to store application-specific data for an event without having to utilize an external database.

You can have the shared properties which are visible and editable by all attendees of an event. This property is shown regardless of the `calendarId` used in the request.

And to add or update events, using patch requests is the preferred method, as it allows you to manipulate some properties while leaving others untouched. Adding a new property with the same key will overwrite any existing properties with the same key.

Please visit the given link for a more detailed information.